# c++: Behavior of push_back() and back() with pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I have two C++ lists, `std::list<T> List1` and `std::list<T*> List2;`. Now, I'd like to do the following operation several times:

```
List1.push_back(new_object);
List2.push_back(&List1.back());
```

My question: Does the reference in List2 stay valid, after each step? I.e.: Is the first element in List2 still referring to the first in List1 etc?

Comment: Don't explain in English what's clearer in C++. Just write `std::list<T> List1;` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it stays valid. `std::list` insertion doesn't invalidate iterators (or pointers to the content in this case).

Comment: A property shared by most containers, but importantly **not** by `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: @MSalters, the price we must pay for cache friendly iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!